# Export python loop results to corresponding columns in Excel using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a loop which retrieves two lists of values from some json.
I would like to export each one of the values list (1000 results each one) with its header to Exscel.
All values are available when I'm printing the results, but Excel sheet contains only header and a single row. Perhaps, I'm missing some loop to add.
Any help is appreciated!

```
list = x.json() 
    
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for item in list:
    item1 = value1['valueID1']
    item2 = value2['valueID2']

    data = {"item1": [item1],"item2": [item2]}

    col_num = 0
    for key, value in data.items():
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, key)
        worksheet.write_column(1, col_num, value)
        col_num += 1
    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increment the row value as well.

```
list = x.json() 
    
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for item in list:
    item1 = value1['valueID1']
    item2 = value2['valueID2']

    data = {"item1": [item1],"item2": [item2]}

    col_num = 0
    row_num = 0

    for key, value in data.items():
        worksheet.write(row_num , col_num, key)
        worksheet.write_column(row_num , col_num, value)
        col_num += 1
    row_num=row_num+1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, this didn't help.

Comment: @l3xand3r you do need to apply this fix. You also need to move the close() out of the loop. You are closing the file on the first iteration.

Comment: @I3xand3r i have edited the code as per jmcnamara comment.

Comment: No luck with this as well... Still get a single row result

Comment: Please post the sample input data for us to test